# Java, end of line with system.out.print

Tags: java, printing, println

I have done some research concerning `System.out.print()` and `System.out.println()` and I discovered that `System.out.println()` add the end of line at the end of printed line.

```
System.out.println("Test");
```

Output only :

```
Test
```

but does not print end of the line.

```
System.out.print("Test");
```

Output only:

```
Test
```

but does not end the line and leave some place for other words or numbers, etc etc.

A more illustrative way is:

```
Test_____________________________________________ (All "blank" spots)
```

Is there a way to, force an end of line with `System.out.print()` directly after the word `Test`? Will the usage of `%` will remove the "blank" spots?

Or a way to code a function that will end the line after I used several `System.out.print()` to print a sentence?

For exemple :

```
System.out.print("Test);
System.out.print("Test);
```

will outpost a pure:

```
Test Test
```

like `System.out.println("Test Test")`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Do you mean like `\n` does?

Comment: `System.out.print("Word\n");` on windows.

Comment: Great job unformatting everything :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can append line separator, Note that it is platform dependant, so :

- Windows ("\r\n")
- Unix/Linux/OSX ("\n")
- pre-OSX Mac ("\r")

If you want to get line separator depending on actual system you can just use :

- `System.getProperty("line.separator");` for pre Java 7
- `System.lineSeparator();` for Java 7

Then you just append your separator to your string in `System.out.print`, like :

- `System.out.print("Word\n");`

Comment: \n is not what I was thinking as I evaluated it in my tests. line.separator is really what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `System.out.print("Test\n")`.

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println("Test");` will print end of the line. When you don't see it in your IDE it doesn't mean it isn't here. Try:

```
System.out.println("Test1");
System.out.println("Test2");
System.out.println("Test3");
```

which will produce:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

From the [docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) of the `println(String)`:

*Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println()*

and from the [docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) of the `println()`:

*Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').*

Answer (score 3):

For getting an OS independent EOL character you could try

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and then appending that to your string ?

Why do you want to manually do that though since there is a function to do it for you ?

Comment: He can just use `System.lineSeparator();` in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly include a newline char in what you are printing:

`System.out.print("Test\n");`

This will force the newline while using the `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a manual newline like so:

`System.out.print("Test\n");`

You can also mix the two when you need to print then end the line like so:

```
System.out.print("This is on ");
System.out.print("the same line.");
System.out.println(" and now we'll end the line");
System.out.println("This is on a different line.");
```